# Connecting Simba ODBC Driver

Tags: c#, odbc, simba

I have configured a Simba ODBC driver in my local Machine, driver is connected and successfully data got from source Database. I am writing a web API to get data from source table. The same configured in our live server which is production server (64 bit), I am getting the following error. some one help me on this..

Thanks in advance.

> ERROR [HY000] [Simba][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data:
> The system cannot find the file specified.\r\nERROR [HY000]
> [Simba][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data: The system
> cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Connecting to Google BigQuery (64 bit) is not supporting in your server convert on (32 bit)

Comment: hi thanks barath.. i have tried with 32 bit ODBC Driver . it is not supporting. please find the   error. ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application